# How to get dynamics routes from URL with Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, internationalization, ember-i18n

How can I get the current router name in Ember with i18n?

I'm trying to make an app with some langs and I need send the user to route coming from the URL.

The routes are dynamic (see the [Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/650f3ff09339b102012ae0846b903aa1?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C)) and I can't get the correct route.

Ex.: **/pt-br/sobre**

The Ember doesn't send the user to lang.about path.

Comment: The twiddle seems to be working correctly? What's the problem?

Comment: @locks, I can't get the current path. The default locale is en. But, if the user access directly a different URL  with another locale and path?

Comment: Your `replaceRoute` call in `changeLang` seems to have too many arguments.